# Disable Ribbon Button

Tags: button, sharepoint-2010, ribbon, ribbon-control

I want to disable and NOT hide a ribbon button (specifically Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem) on a particular List type. On web I could find a lot many posts showing me ways to remove/hide buttons but none really worthwhile which could tell me how can I just disable an alrteady existing sharepoint button in my custom List type.

e.g. Following code does remove the button instead of hiding.

Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
  RegistrationType="List"
  RegistrationId="213908"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through Javascript on the client side.  Check out this article for an example.
http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-ribbon-customization_23.html