# How to disable button of Ribbon ToolBar?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon, ribbon-control

**[Possible Duplicate]**
[Disable Ribbon Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958219/disable-ribbon-button)
But I came with question, as I'm this question not answered and I'm looking for available server side solution.

I wonder if there is a way to disable button or many buttons from Ribbon toolbar from server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Ribbon.TrimById Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff412411.aspx) you can locate Ribbon, RibbonButton or RibbonGroup to hide.

[Complete sample to hide Ribbon buttons sharepoint 2010 programmatically](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/10/24/hide-ribbon-buttons-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to look into the HideCustomAction option of the Feature Framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790.aspx

It has the ability to hide some aspects of the default UI elements in the product and the documentation does talk about the Ribbon so it may do what you want.